# Adding image in title

Tags: posts

I am having some trouble with wordpress. First time user.

How do you add an image in the title space in a post on wordpress.

Can someone help ? Thank you

Comment: A title is text and even if there might be hacky ways to kind of make this work I do not believe it is a good idea. Can you elaborate on the use case so we can maybe help you find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you cannot add an image to the title field. That is for text only.

You can however use "featured images."

Here is the documentation for [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

Here is a [concise article for implementing featured images](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-featured-image-url/) to go along with your post title. To implement something like this, you would have to add the code manually to your theme file.

Answer (score 0):

The way a site looks, is mostly controlled by it's theme. Most themes don't have a place to put an image in the title, although you could easily create a place in PHP. Also, you could hard code an individual image in most themes, by just typing:

```
<img src = "http://yourdomain.comnet/location-of-image/image.jpg" />
```

into the title.